# How to open the "Choose a Group" dialog in Telegram via bot

Tags: api, bots, telegram

How can the "Select a Group" dialog be opened for a user via bot?
[image: Image of dialog]

The closest I got was to open all the chat by using `switch_inline_query` of `InlineKeyboardButton` but that is not the same.

I actually first saw it from a bot so I know bots can do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok got it! Had to change the `url` of `InlineKeyboardButton` to `'url' => 'https://t.me/<MYBOTUSERNAME>?startgroup=c'`